# running and stopping a script in subprocess

Tags: python

I am not familiar with subprocesses and I would like to have some help with the following problem.
I have 3 apps. Lets say I am running them with command like this:

```
python manage.py app1
python manage.py app2
python manage.py app2
```

I want to make a main script to control them like `run_app1` or `stop_app1`

Everything runs in linux.

My apologies for my poor explanation. I have a problem called Dyslexia, also known as reading disorder. It is some times hard for me to write down what I am thinking.
Thank you for reading or any help

Comment: Just fixed the obvious grammar and formatting. Question needs more details from OP

Comment: Please try to provide compete information. Are those apps producing/consuming any data and how much? Is there any interaction between those apps at all or do they only need to be started and stopped? By stopping them, do you mean sending them some signal to complete and exit or killing them as a process in the middle of what they are doing?

Comment: @isp-zax thank you for your comment, yeah they producing data. i have them writing in a .txt when they done with the processing of the data. and when they write in the txt 'done' i want to close them and i mean killing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `subprocess` Python module a first step could be something like this:

```py
# Master
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import socket
import sys

port = 10000
lstn = Listener(('localhost', int(port)), authkey=b'secret')
proc = Popen((sys.executable, 'worker.py', str(port)), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

conn = lstn.accept()
conn.send([1, 'Brian', None])
print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

```py
# Worker
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import sys

port = int(sys.argv[1])
conn = Client(('localhost', port), authkey=b'secret')

while True:
    try:
        msg = conn.recv()
        print('Received: %s', str(msg))
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except EOFError:
        break
```

The master process initializes a listener and then opens the worker process. Messages can be sent to the worker via the connection object and `stdout` and `stderr` go back to the master process.